# React Functional Component - Use Callback and Props at Same Time

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn React JSX as pretty new. I want to use Callback function from my Parent component and props at same time but I couldn't handle with this. I've tried a lot of combinations like **({childToParent}, props)** - **({childToParent, props})**

I always gets an different error. I just want to define my "childToParent" callback and props on my Child component. May anyone help me please? Thanks a lot!

*P.S: List component is my child component's name*

```
export default function List(props, {childToParent}) {

....

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the callback *into* the props:

```
// Parent calls child:
<List someProp="foo" childToParent={someCallback} />
```

```
// Child:
const List = ({ someProp, childToParent }) => {
  // use someProp and childToParent here
};
```